# Update a mutable map with default value in Scala

Tags: scala, dictionary

Consider the following code that counts the frequency of each string in the list and stores the results in the mutable map. This works great, but I don't understand where the += method is defined?! Is this some weird implicit conversion thing or what? I saw this code somewhere but it didn't include an explanation for the +=.

```
val list = List("a", "b", "a")
val counts = new scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String, Int]().withDefaultValue(0)
list.foreach(counts(_) += 1)
counts
//> res7: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(a -> 2, b -> 1)
```

The apply of map returns an Int, but Int doesn't have a += and this method updates the map with a new value, so it looks as if the apply returns a mutable integer that has a += method...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not an implicit conversion - it is a desugaring.
Writing:

```
x += 1
```

desugars to:

```
x = x + 1
```

if the class of `x` does not have a `+=` method defined on it.

In the same way:

```
counts("a") += 1
```

desugars to:

```
counts("a") = counts("a") + 1
```

because `counts("a")` is an `Int`, and `Int` does not have a `+=` method defined.

On the other hand, writing:

```
x(expression1) = expression2
```

desugars to a call to the `update` method in Scala:

```
x.update(expression1, expression2)
```

Every mutable `Map` has an `update` method [defined](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.Map) - it allows setting keys in the map.

So the entire expression is desugared to:

```
list.foreach(x => counts.update(x, counts(x) + 1))
```

This `+=` is not to be confused with the `+=` method on `mutable.Map`s in Scala. That method updates the entry in the map if that key already existed, or adds a new key-value pair. It returns the `this` reference, that is, the same map, so you can chain `+=` calls. See [ScalaDoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.Map) or the [source code](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.0/src/library/scala/collection/mutable/MapLike.scala#L89).

Comment: Yes, `+=` from `mutable.Map` is never called above. The `counts("a") += 1` is desugared into `counts("a") = counts("a") + 1`, which is further desugared into an `update` call on the map.

Comment: Ok thanks guys that double desugaring explanation makes sense! I removed my first comment that was based on @axel22 first answer that he then modified. Anyway, now it makes sense, thanks! :D

Answer (score 3):

For these moments where you wonder what compiler magic is happening in a part of your code, `scalac -print` is your best friend (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784926/how-can-i-see-in-what-java-scala-code-does-scala-compiler-rewrites-original-s)).

If you do a `scalac -print C.scala` where C.scala is

```
package test

class C {
    def myMethod() {
        val counts = new scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String, Int]().withDefaultValue(0)
        counts("a") += 1
    }
}
```

you get

```
package test {
  class C extends Object {
    def myMethod(): Unit = {
      val counts: collection.mutable.Map = new collection.mutable.HashMap().withDefaultValue(scala.Int.box(0));
      counts.update("a", scala.Int.box(scala.Int.unbox(counts.apply("a")).+(1)))
    };
    def <init>(): test.C = {
      C.super.<init>();
      ()
    }
  }
```

It came as a surprise for me also, but apparently scalac will transform

```
map(key) =<op> rhs
```

to

```
map.update(key, map.apply(key) <op> rhs)
```