# Writing Macro for Positive Integers

Tags: scala, scala-macros

Given the following types:

```
sealed trait PosIntCheckResult
case class LteZero(x: Int) extends PosIntCheckResult
case object NotConstant extends PosIntCheckResult
```

I'm trying to write a macro that checks whether the given `Int` is greater than 0.

```
import reflect.macros.Context

def getInt(c: Context)(value: c.Expr[Int]): Either[PosIntCheckResult, Int] = {

    import c.universe._

    value.tree match {
        case Literal(Constant(x)) => if (x > 0) Right(x) else Left(LteZero(x))
        case _                    => Left(NotConstant)
    }
}
```

But `Any` shows up for the `x` value:

```
Test.scala:29: type mismatch;
  found   : Any
  required: Int
    case Literal(Constant(x)) => 
       if (x > 0) Right(x) else Left(LteZero(x))
```

How can I get the compiler to expect an `Int` rather than `Any`?

Comment: Except for literal, I can hardly see an easy way to check whether an `Int` value is positive (e.g. `def foo(x: Int) = ???` hard to check `x` before runtime). You may want to have a look at https://github.com/non/spire/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Kind of off topic but you may be interested in my blog post [here](https://meta.plasm.us/posts/2013/10/03/natural-vampires/) for a macro-based solution to a similar problem.

Comment: somewhat related question in the scalatest forum - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scalatest-users/guIlCXHbgh8

Answer (score 1):

You just have to match on patterns where `x` is an `Int`:

```
case Literal(Constant(x: Int)) => //When using x here, it is an Int
```

Read about pattern matching on type and the other types of pattern matching in the [docs](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/pattern-matching.html).

You should also note that your macro will need to return an `Expr` in order to work.  You can use `reify` to construct the desired `Exprs` at each `case`.  Read about `reify` and `def macros` [here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/overview.html).  I'm not sure why this needs to be a macro, but if you're just learning the techniques, something like this might work:

```
object Macros {
    def getInt(value: Int): Either[PosIntCheckResult, Int] = macro getIntImpl

    def getIntImpl(c: Context)(value: c.Expr[Int]): c.Expr[Either[PosIntCheckResult,Int]] = {

        import c.universe._

        value.tree match {
            case x@Literal(Constant(const: Int)) if const > 0 => reify(Right(c.Expr[Int](x).splice))
            case x@Literal(Constant(_: Int)) => reify(Left(LteZero(c.Expr[Int](x).splice)))
            case _  => reify(Left(NotConstant))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But this approach uses `asInstanceOf`? Is it a compile-time check?

Comment: Pattern matching like this doesn't use `asInstanceOf`.  This is a pattern matching syntax.  It is checked at compile time, and will only match that case if `x` is an `Int`.

Comment: But how about this [gist](https://gist.github.com/kevinmeredith/2575581c71e51c23da17)? I have not read JVM bytecode very much, but I see `instanceOf` in the instructions. Lastly, this post shows `isInstanceOf` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3785053/409976), no?

Comment: @KevinMeredith Yeah, the type cases here will desugar to runtime checks with `isInstanceOf`, and in general you're right to avoid that, but if there's anywhere it's probably not a big deal it's code that runs at compile time.