# Interpreting NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I'm running into this when running some code that's different at compile time

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.physical.ClusteredDistribution$.apply$default$2()'
```

Class at compile time:

```
case class ClusteredDistribution(
    clustering: Seq[Expression],
    requiredNumPartitions: Option[Int] = None) extends Distribution {
  require(
    clustering != Nil,
    "The clustering expressions of a ClusteredDistribution should not be Nil. " +
      "An AllTuples should be used to represent a distribution that only has " +
      "a single partition.")
}
```

Class at run time:

```
case class ClusteredDistribution(
    clustering: Seq[Expression],
    requireAllClusterKeys: Boolean = SQLConf.get.getConf(
      SQLConf.REQUIRE_ALL_CLUSTER_KEYS_FOR_DISTRIBUTION),
    requiredNumPartitions: Option[Int] = None) extends Distribution {
  require(
    clustering != Nil,
    "The clustering expressions of a ClusteredDistribution should not be Nil. " +
      "An AllTuples should be used to represent a distribution that only has " +
      "a single partition.")
}
```

is this exception complaining about parameter `requireAllClusterKeys` with default value `SQLConf.get.getConf( SQLConf.REQUIRE_ALL_CLUSTER_KEYS_FOR_DISTRIBUTION)` because that parameter doesn't exist at compile time? I'm assuming this is the case because otherwise I don't know how the `boolean` in that exception is relevant. Basically what I think is happening is that this case class is instantiated at runtime using a boolean parameter, but the class in the compiled jar doesn't have a boolean parameter thus failing to find the method being called

I've been reading other posts about interpreting these exceptions such as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2945862/interpreting-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-message) but mine is different in that the namespace is prefaced with `boolean` and I don't know how to interpret `.apply$default$2()` (which I'm assuming is just complaining about a default parameter in the apply method)

Comment: If you don't have same classes at compile time and runtime, this is definitely the kind of errors you'll get. Make sure you compile using the same version of Spark that you'll be running on.

Comment: @GaëlJ I understand how this type of exception can occur. I just don't know how to interpret this specific one

Comment: Are you supposed to fix the exception, or interpret it?

Comment: @Kayaman I'm supposed to interpret it

Comment: This is kinda the internals of the Scala compiler. If you really want to understand, I guess you should look at the compiled code and "map" it to the source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the javadocs of [NoSuchMethodError](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/NoSuchMethodError.html)

> Thrown if an application tries to call a specified method of a class (either static or instance), and that class no longer has a definition of that method.
>
> Normally, this error is caught by the compiler; this error can only occur at run time if the definition of a class has incompatibly changed.

Based on the details of the question, I guess you were able to compile the project because you have the correct dependency set during the compilation time, but at runtime you used another version.

---

- From `scala spark sql 3.2.4`: [ClusteredDistribution](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v3.2.4/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/plans/physical/partitioning.scala#L73)  (similar to the one from compile time)

```scala
case class ClusteredDistribution(
    clustering: Seq[Expression],
    requiredNumPartitions: Option[Int] = None) extends Distribution {
  require(
    clustering != Nil,
    "The clustering expressions of a ClusteredDistribution should not be Nil. " +
      "An AllTuples should be used to represent a distribution that only has " +
      "a single partition.")
```

- From `scala spark sql 3.4.1`: [ClusteredDistribution](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v3.4.1/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/plans/physical/partitioning.scala#L82)  (similar to the one from runtime)

```scala
case class ClusteredDistribution(
    clustering: Seq[Expression],
    requireAllClusterKeys: Boolean = SQLConf.get.getConf(
      SQLConf.REQUIRE_ALL_CLUSTER_KEYS_FOR_DISTRIBUTION),
    requiredNumPartitions: Option[Int] = None) extends Distribution {
  require(
    clustering != Nil,
    "The clustering expressions of a ClusteredDistribution should not be Nil. " +
      "An AllTuples should be used to represent a distribution that only has " +
      "a single partition.")
```

As you can see, the constructor of each `case class` is different. They don't have the same signature. So, if you compile the project using one version and during runtime you have another version where they don't have the same signature, you can end in that type of error.

---

You want to understand the error message that says

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.physical.ClusteredDistribution$.apply$default$2()'
```

Lets try to throw the same error message. To do that, we can create a project `compile` with two files.

- `Main.scala`

```scala
object Main extends App {
  new ClusteredDistribution(Seq("Hello"))
}
```

- `ClusteredDistribution.scala` (similar to the class at compile time)

```scala
class ClusteredDistribution(
  clustering: Seq[String],
  requireAllClusterKeys: Boolean = true,
  requiredNumPartitions: Option[Int] = None
)
```

then compile the project using `scalac`

```scala
scalac *.scala
```

Then create another project called `runtime` just using the `*.class` files generated from the `runtime` project

```scala
cp compile/*.class runtime/
```

inside `runtime` project create a new `ClusteredDistribution.scala` with the following code

```scala
class ClusteredDistribution(
  clustering: Seq[String],
  requiredNumPartitions: Option[Int] = None
)
```

compile just this class

```scala
scalac *.scala
```

and then run the `Main` class with

```scala
scala Main
```

there you are, a similar error message

```scala
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean ClusteredDistribution$.$lessinit$greater$default$2()'
```

---

from [How can I see in what [Java/Scala?] code does Scala compiler rewrites original Scala-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784926/how-can-i-see-in-what-java-scala-code-does-scala-compiler-rewrites-original-s)

> use "scalac -print" to compile it, you will get the following Scala code

If we try to compile the files we created in the previous step with that flag, this is what you get

- from `compile` (`<init>$default$2(): Boolean`)

```scala
[[syntax trees at end of                   cleanup]] // ClusteredDistribution.scala
package <empty> {
  class ClusteredDistribution extends Object {
    def <init>(clustering: Seq, requireAllClusterKeys: Boolean, requiredNumPartitions: Option): ClusteredDistribution = {
      ClusteredDistribution.super.<init>();
      ()
    }
  };
  <synthetic> object ClusteredDistribution extends Object {
    <synthetic> def <init>$default$2(): Boolean = true;
    <synthetic> def <init>$default$3(): Option = scala.None;
    def <init>(): ClusteredDistribution.type = {
      ClusteredDistribution.super.<init>();
      ()
    }
  }
}
```

- from `runtime` (`<init>$default$2(): Option`)

```scala
[[syntax trees at end of                   cleanup]] // ClusteredDistribution.scala
package <empty> {
  class ClusteredDistribution extends Object {
    def <init>(clustering: Seq, requiredNumPartitions: Option): ClusteredDistribution = {
      ClusteredDistribution.super.<init>();
      ()
    }
  };
  <synthetic> object ClusteredDistribution extends Object {
    <synthetic> def <init>$default$2(): Option = scala.None;
    def <init>(): ClusteredDistribution.type = {
      ClusteredDistribution.super.<init>();
      ()
    }
  }
}
```

From there, we can observe that the number from `$default$2` is related with the position of the parameter where you put a default value. You can also see that there is a `$default$3` for the one from `compile` project which belong to the third param of the class.

---

You can find that in [http4s 0.23.23](https://github.com/http4s/http4s), for keeping binary compatibility with `http4s 0.23.12`, they did the following in [Multipart](https://github.com/http4s/http4s/blob/v0.23.23/core/shared/src/main/scala/org/http4s/multipart/Multipart.scala#L48) companion object

```scala
object Multipart {
  @deprecated("Retaining for binary-compatibility", "0.23.12")
  def `<init>$default$2`: String = apply$default$2
  @deprecated("Retaining for binary-compatibility", "0.23.12")
  def apply$default$2: String = Boundary.unsafeCreate().value

  @deprecated(
    "Creating a boundary is an effect.  Use Multiparts.multipart to generate an F[Multipart[F]], or call the two-parameter apply with your own boundary.",
    "0.23.12",
  )
  def apply[F[_]](parts: Vector[Part[F]]) = new Multipart(parts)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for actually answering the question!